# Maximum sum of 1 to n numbers where the sum should never be equal to given integer k

Tags: algorithm

how to find the maximum sum of the numbers starting from 1 to n but at any time the current sum should never be equal to a given number k.

This is what I have done but its not correct all the time.

```
static int maxMoney(int n, long k) {
    int currentSum = 0;
   for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
       currentSum += i;
       if(currentSum == k){
           currentSum -= 1;
           continue;
       }
   }
  return currentSum;  
}
```

> **constraints**

```
   1<= n <= 2 * 10^9
    1<= k <= 4*10^15
```

So if n = 3 and k = 3;
 and if we add 1 + 2 we get 3, we reject 1 and start at 2 and do 2+3 to get 5. 
We can also do 1+3 and we get the value 4 in this case but since we want maximum we choose 5 over 4 and hence 5 is the answer in this case.

Comment: What have you tried? What language are you using?

Comment: Do you have to add the numbers in order?

Comment: Do you have to actually add them one by one, or can you use mathematical properties to shortcut some calculations, like `1+2+...+n = n(n+1)/2`

Comment: We are free to use any properties, but I dont see how this property you mentioned can be used here.

Comment: What about Dave's question? Sum in order?

Comment: Yes we have to, but the moment the sum is equal to k at any time we have to leave some integers and yet get the maximum value at the end.

Comment: Hint: if the sum is never equal to k, the answer is obviously n * (n - 1) / 2. Let's assume that it's equal to k at some point. What happens if we throw away 1?

Comment: If k = 5, and we take 1, then 1+2, then 1+2+3... should it be rejected because 2+3 = 5?

Comment: @kraskevich But to check the sum is never equal to k we have to proceed in sequence from 1 to n. and if we throw 1 away our sum will never be equal to k.

Comment: @JohnDoe You just need to solve one quadratic equation to check if it's ever equal to `k`.

Comment: @trincot 1+2+3 will not be rejected.

Comment: So then there are two options: either sum all numbers, or all numbers except 1 (i.e. 2+3+...+n). Take the first if no conflict with *k*, otherwise the second. And the second does not need a separate calculation of course, it is just the first minus 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume first you can just sum all numbers: `sum = 1+2+...+n`, which can be calculated as `sum = n(n+1)/2`.

Then check if there is an *i* between 1 and *n*, such that `1+2+...+i = k`. If not, then the previously calculated sum is the solution.

If there is such *i*, then reject 1, and return `sum - 1`.

Determine whether such *i* exists by solving the following equation:

```
k = i(i+1)/2
```

This quadratic equation has this positive solution:

```
i = (sqrt(1+8k) - 1) / 2
```

If this *i* is an integer number, and it is within the interval *1...n*, then we have indeed found such an *i*. Otherwise, we can conclude that *k* will never be equal to *1+2+...+i* for any *i* in the interval *1...n*.

So here is a little JavaScript function that implements this:

```js
function getSum(n, k) {
    var sum, i;
    
    sum = n*(n+1)/2;
    i = (Math.sqrt(1+8*k) - 1) / 2;
    if (i === Math.floor(i) && i <= n)
        sum--;
    return sum;
}

// Sample call
console.log(getSum(3, 3)); // = 5
```